# Number of e-foldings in inflationary cosmology

Tags: cosmology, cosmological-inflation

Is there a physical principle limiting the number of e-foldins during cosmological inflation? What is the upper bound on the possible number of e-foldings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, there is not limit. But we are usually interested in the "observable" inflation which is limited to around $50-60$ e-folds, depending on the model. "Observable" means that we can observe the density fluctuations generated during those $50-60$ e-folds, as CMB fluctuations. The fluctuations generated earlier than $60$ e-folds before the end of inflation are (currently) unobservable.

Comment: That is, 50-60 e-foldings is the lower limit, but there is no upper limit?

Comment: 50 is the lower limit, 60 is the upper limit, roughly speaking

Comment: again, upper limit on observable inflation, non-observable part is not limited in principle

Comment: I did not understand. You said that there is no upper limit. Or do you mean that 50 to 60 e-foldings is necessary to be consistent with observations, but the number could be more than 60?

Comment: I seem to understand. That is, we are talking about the last 50-60 e-foldings preceding the end of inflation.

Comment: @ArmanArmenpress yes, the last 50-60 e-folds are necessary, and observable today, but the actual inflation may be longer, we just cannot see it